# startDrag() flash moving all parent objects instead of just what it is assigned to

Tags: flash, actionscript

so I am fairly new to Actionscript, but I've been getting on quite well with functions and event listeners so I was wondering if anyone could possibly tell me a fix for what is happening with my project.

So I have a basic drag and drop function, but when I run this code it is moving everything on the stage, from all the different layers and frames and I don't want this to happen, I just want the assorted object to drag

```
answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, answer1_drag)
function answer1_drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
startDrag();
}

answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, answer1_drop)
function answer1_drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
stopDrag();
}
```

I can't think of anything wrong with the code but I would appreciate the help, Thanks guys!

EDIT: Motion Suggests

```
if(answer1_word.hitTestObject(word_select_box)){
trace("Hello");
}
```

This is my hit test object code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling startDrag() and stopDrag() on the "root" level container. That is the "stage". You need to call startDrag() and stopDrag() from the instance you want to move.

```
answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, answer1_drag)
function answer1_drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
 answer1_word.startDrag();
}

answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, answer1_drop)
function answer1_drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
 answer1_word.stopDrag();
}
```

Honestly if you are planning on having more than one Draggle object, I would abstract away using event.target

```
answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag)
answer1_word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop)

function onDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.target.startDrag();
}


function onDrop(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Honestly man that has really helped, thankyou and you are definitely the accepted answer :), but I am having one more problem if you wouldn't mind helping with you knowledge of AS3? :)

Comment: Aiden go ahead and post it, and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Well using this code taking the advice you give me I am having problem using hitTestObject, as it is not detecting the obeject at all, I have tried tracing results from output and nothing is working, if you could help It'd be much appreciated! The edit is inside of my original code